# Video pixelated issue in Wowza RTSP streaming using Amazon S3

Tags: rtsp, wowza

I am using Wowza streaming server (VODS3) on Amazon EC2 and files on S3 bucket.
Videos are played via RTSP.

RTSP is working fine, but the video quality is not good. Video gets pixelated in between.

I've taken Wowza from Amazon market place.

Do I need to set any configuration or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying the default sample.mp4 file that comes with your install of Wowza.  Upload that to your s3 account and try playing that back and see if there is a difference? You might use ffmpeg to [encode your custom files](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?192-How-to-encode-video-on-demand-content) prior to uploading to s3 to ensure smooth playback.  If you are playing back on Android device, you may also try (depending on manufacturer and version) hls playback.